# Issue on Setting UI Slider For Opacity Amount

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Can you please take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/am1xmL9p/) and let me know how I can use the slider to get values from `0` to `1`  like `0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1`

Here is what I have

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      value:1,
      min: 0,
      max: 1,
      step: 10,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#opacity" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#opacity" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="amount">Opacity:</label>
  <input type="text" id="opacity" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
 
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your step value is too high, try:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    value:1,
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    step: 0.1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#opacity" ).val( ui.value );
    }
 });
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/am1xmL9p/1/)

---

[New fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/am1xmL9p/3/)

Comment: Thanks JTG, I just wonder if there is a way to get the values without  steps  on slider? I mean having a smooth slide

Comment: Do you mean you want the slider to be smooth but the only valid values to be 0, .1, .2, .3.....?  Or do you just want a smooth slider with the values to be between 0 and 1 but not stepped incrementally?

Comment: Thanks again for reply, I need to have the slider  to be smooth but the only valid values to be 0, .1, .2, .3.....1

Comment: Okay, check out the latest fiddle. I've decreased the step to (0.01) and then rounded the value to the nearest .1 value.  Hopefully this works for you.